# How to upload web-app files to Windows Server on Amazon EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, npm, gulp

How can I upload web-app files from my pc to Amazon EC2 VPC - Windows Server 2012 R2 during the development of the web-app? The files are static files (HTML, JS, CSS) and `web.config` file. Preferably it should be automated via Gulp or NPM. I am looking for the best practise solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Amazon EC2 instance is nothing but a remote server.
You can connect to it just like you connect to any other computer.
The following guide describes how to do it:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html

After you are logged in, you can configure any deployment system per your choice.

Comment: Thanks. Well I use remote desktop to install all the required programs on the EC2 machine. The idea was however to be able to upload the files automatically from the development machine without actually login to the EC2 machine via remote desktop so that I can automate it via command line. I was thinking of VPN or FTP but I do not know if I should use these in this case not to open doors for hacks plus VPN seems to be a paid service on Amazon.

Comment: I understand your idea. My point is that after logging in to EC2 via RDP you can do anything you want. For example install FTP server, install GIt, or simply create a network share. After you perfrom this step, you can proceed with your automation per your choice.